# How to use templateUrl in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, state, angularjs-routing

in my file home.js have

```
.state('app.profile', {
    url : '/profile',
    views : {
        'appContent' : {
            templateUrl: '../templates/profile.html',
            controller: 'HomeController'
        }
    }
})
```

in my file profile.html have this

```
<ion-view title="Profile">
  <ion-content>
    <!--somethings here-->
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

My directory

```
js
  home.js
templates
  profile.html
```

But I can't make it work. Please help me to fix this error!

Comment: This old question doesn't seem to explain what the problem is/was, so I am voting to close. Do please edit if you can.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you must do so:

```
.state('index', {
    url : '/route1',
    templateUrl: '../templates/profile.html',
    controller: 'Controller'
})
```

if you want to use multiple views:

```
.state('index', {
    url: "/route1",
    views: {
      "viewA": { template: "index.viewA" },
      "viewB": { template: "index.viewB" }
    }
})
```

Comment: No no I mean that: I have this code in my index.html file
  <script id="profile.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view title="Profile">
      <ion-content padding="true">
        <!--some code here-->
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
  </script>
But I want to separate them into 2 file. I copy main of <script> into profile.html and change templateUrl of this state but it doesn't work.
May be, I don't know how to use templateUrl. :(